# @ManyToMany:How to avoid the extra update in table B when inserting in table A,Join Table

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i have two tables:

**Authority**, **Permission** they have **many to many** relationship

```
class Authority{

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "authority_permission", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<Permission> permissions = new ArrayList<Permission>(0);

}
```

some times i need to create a **new Authority** and assign to it some **existing permissions** (**insert** data in **authority** , **authority_permission** only) as follows:

```
List<Permission> permissions=new ArrayList<Permission>;
Permission permission=permissionDao.getPermissionById(1); 
permissions.add(permission);   
authority.setPermissions(permissions)
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(authority).
```

above code, works fine, but i noticed that hibernate makes an **extra update** in **permission** table, which is not needed, since there are no changes in permission table:

```
Hibernate: insert into authority (description, display_name, is_default, name, authority_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update permission set description=?, display_name=?, name=? where permission_id=?
Hibernate: insert into role_permission (role_id, permission_id) values (?, ?)
```

any ideas how to avoid this extra update ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the cascade type annotation

Comment: change it to what, please specify.